# Синхронизация проекта на 2 устройствах Visual Studio (2019)

Tags: visual-studio, git

Делаю проекты (в основном на C#) в Visual Studio 2019 на стационарном компьютере и часто еть необходимость продолжить решение задачи на ноутбуке. Хотелось бы узнать, как можно синхронизировать проект, чтобы можно было продолжить работу над той же задачей с того же места, в общем чтобы код автоматически добавлялся на другое устройство без создания коммитов в Git системе (чтобы не образовывалось много коммитов и на случай, если забыл закоммитить)?

Comment: есть мысль, что можно синхронизировать каталог с проектом с помощью OneDrive, либо разместить его в каком-либо сетевом расположении, доступном для обоих компьютеров

Comment: Легче приучить себя коммитить когда встаешь сходить за печеньками или в туалет. Чем страдать с конфликтами порождёнными DropBox и другими облачными хранилищами. Этот навык вам еще пригодится когда устроитесь на работу. А коммитов не нужно бояться, если переживаете за флуд, то правильней создать ветку, коммитить в нее, а когда работа будет завершена, то подмёрджить ее. Ну и плюс современные IDE позволяют подсвечивать изменения, поэтому легче найти будет код, который менялся со времени последнего коммита. Я даже этим пользуюсь локально для удобства, а при необходимости импортирую репозиторий

Comment: Всегда можно комитить не в опубликованную ветку, потом дальше проводить подготовительную работу: переразбивать на комиты, писать им красивые сообщения и тому подобное.

Comment: Раз Git не подходит, то остаётся два варианта DropBox и прочие аналоги или почитать про collaborate visual studio: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/use/vs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стал использовать для синхронизации backup and sync from google. Программа синхронизирует выбранные папки и так же создаёт общую папку (которая в начал автоматически создаётся где-то в диске С, но если в начале её удалить, то можно выбрать другую папку с любым названием), которая синхронизирует её содержимое. Там поместил все основные проекты. Есть так же программы с аналогичным функционалом от Яндекс и есть OneDrive, но выбрал Google, т.к. им чаще пользуюсь. Но программа иногда  не удаляет временные файлы и не мгновенно при включении ноутбука синхронизирует данные с google диска. Так же при выключении компьютера нужно немного подождать завершения синхронизации с диском. В общем в целом это решает проблему, но лучше минимум раз в пару дней делать коммиты проектом, над которым идёт работа. Удобно кстати в данной папке хранить и документы и рефераты — в дальнейшем их можно открыть со смартфона в приложении гугл диска или на компьютере в универе.